# function to plot a dendrogram for x,y,z coordinates in R

Tags: r

for the following dental.csv file

```
item,x,y,z
A1,66,89,122
A2,14,44,-9
A3,-17,199,11
A35,99,0,12
test,15,144,15
```

i wrote the following R Script

```
mycoord<-read.csv("dental.csv")
d<-dist(mycoord)
h<-hclust(d)
plot(h, lab=mycoord$item)
```

this matches the "test" coordinates to the closest value as follows

[image]

what i need to do is a function that takes integer x,y,z and place them in the dataframe as "test", then plot the dendrogram. any help?

another thing, for the same R Script above i added the following

```
newdata<-mycoord[,2:4]
heatmap(as.matrix(newdata))
```

i get the following chart

[image]

for some reason, i cant add labels to the heatmap (i mean "A3", "A4", etc.. instead of "1","2","3", etc..) I get error when use the parameter **lab=mycoord$item**

Comment: Sorry, don't quite follow. What are the labels you're looking for in the final dendrogram?

Comment: a1, a2, a3 and a35 are standard coordinates as x,y,z. i need to put the test coordinate and the when the function runs i get the closest value to coordinates. in this example the "test" coordinates are nearest to "A3". i dont want to put the "test" coordinates in the CSV file i want them to be plotted "run-time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about loading your CSV without `test` first like this:

```
df <- read.csv(header=T, text="item,x,y,z
A1,66,89,122
A2,14,44,-9
A3,-17,199,11
A35,99,0,12")
```

Then load `test` as:

```
test <- data.frame(item="test", x=15, y=144, z=15)
```

Then, calculate distance by using `rbind` as:

```
d <- dist(rbind(df[,2:4], test[,2:4]))
h <- hclust(d)
plot(h, labels=c(as.character(df$item), as.character(test$item)))
```

Is this what you require?

For the second part:

```
dd <- rbind(df, test)
dd.m <- as.matrix(dd[,2:4])
row.names(dd.m) <- dd[,1]
heatmap(dd.m)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, my vote up. Would you please take a look at the second part of my question? (heatmap labels)

Answer (score 2):

Is it so, that you just want to have a function that takes your original data matrix and then a test matrix, combines it and feeds it then into your clustering? Somethink like

```
testClust <- function(data,test){
    mycoord <- rbind(data,test)
    d<-dist(mycoord)
    h<-hclust(d)
    plot(h, lab=mycoord$item)
}
```

Comment: (+1) better than `rbind`ing every time (if the OP wants to use many `test` cases.